# Populate drop down choice list with site collections title property

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, list

I have a list (SP2010) which is used to record payments from different offices. I have created a WorkFlow that emails the accounts team with the details. I have also created a new custom form for the list.

The issue I face is that we have 10 regions each with 10 live offices. The offices come and go so the list is constantly updating. At the moment the end user, when filling in the form, chooses the region from a drop down list and then in the next field **manually** types in the office name in a simple text field. The reason they manually type the office name is because I do not want to have to keep updating this 'Office' field every time a new office is commissioned or decommissioned.

An issue with this approach is that one end user may call the office *London* with a capitol *L* and another user may call it *london* with a lower case *l*, another user may call it *London, UK*. Basically I have no consistency so ultimately this causes more dilemmas down the road in reporting.

Now each time a new office is commissioned a site collection is created but I do not have the skills to develop this list field to look at site collections and populate this list field with the site collection title property!

What options do I have available to me? I am running SharePoint 2010 Enterprise and using SharePoint Designer 2010, I have very basic developing skills.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use Managed Metadata for this, it's made exactly for this very reason.

1. Go to "Term Store Management" under "Site Administration"
2. Create a "New Group" by clicking on the arrow right next to root icon you see in the left pane of the center panel you see in front of you.

If you are unable to find this option, give yourself or ask the SharePoint administrator for the permission to manage the Managed Metadata Service (You can find the service itself under Service Applications in Central Administration).

1. Add a "New term set" to this group called "SharePoint sites"
2. Add your values under this
3. Add all synonyms and various translations to each term
4. After you're done with the store, go back to "Site Settings"
5. Follow through into "Site columns" under the Galleries category
6. Click Create and select "Managed Metadata" from the list
7. Under term set settings, select the term set you've made.
8. Add the column to your list.

Comment: Chris, thanks for the swift reply. I have thought o MMS for this dilemma but would this auto update itself or would we have to manage the term set each time a new office is provisioned?

Comment: Yes, the managed metadata store is something that needs to be maintained. You can open the term set so that people can add new terms themselves, but again this asks for proper maitenance for merging terms, etc. But it's centralized, you just have to maintain it in one location throughout the environment. The experience is relatively painless, I like working with it.

Comment: I know we have the service running already so I will acquaint myself with it and see if it can solve this issue. Thanks